# How can I check if AWS S3 sync has any changes?

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line, amazon-s3, salt-stack

I have some files in an Amazon S3 bucket, and I'm using SaltStack to copy all of those files to a directory on a minion.

Unfortunately, SaltStack doesn't have the abilty to copy an entire directory from S3 (yet), so I've resorted to using the [awscli](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html). It works almost perfectly.

It can sync the S3 bucket and my directory (hooray!), and it even has a `--dryrun` flag (even better!), but unfortunately I cannot figure out a way to make it do *something* that I can capture with Salt to say that there are no changes.

I have a Salt state that looks like this:

```
copy-my-dir:
  file.directory:
    - name: /path/to/my/dir
    - makedirs: True
  cmd.run:
    - name: "aws s3 sync s3://my-bucket/ /path/to/my/dir"
    - unless: "What goes here?"
```

I've tried `--dry-run` for "what goes here?" but aws s3 sync returns 0 whether there are files to sync or not.

I tried `aws --output json s3 sync --dry-run` but that doesn't even come close to doing anything useful (i.e. it doesn't output JSON that I can tell, at least not when running via `salt 'minion' cmd.run "aws..."`.

So how can I tell if there are any differences between my Amazon S3 bucket and my directory so I can conditionally execute a SaltStack state?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out that the wonderful `grep` utility can do exactly what I need:

```
- onlyif: "aws s3 sync --dryrun s3://my-bucket /path/to/my/dir" | grep download"
```

If there's something to do, awscli will output `download: <filename>`, but if the directories are synced up then there is no output.

Comment: This is a great solution, but I recommend being a little more precise with the grep pattern to avoid false positives. `^download:` would be safer.